# How can I install netcdf4-python to ubuntu14.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, netcdf

I would like to install netcdf4-python to my Ubuntu14.04. The libhdf5-dev_1.8.11_5ubuntu7_amd64.deb and libnetcdf-4.1.3-7ubuntu2_amd64.deb are installed.  I downloaded netcdf4-1.1.8.tar.gz from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netCDF4#downloads
I tried configure it by

```
./configure --enable-netcdf-4 –with-hdf5=/usr/include/ --enable-share –prefix=/usr
```

but I got the following message:

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

I do not know how I can install netcdf4-python. 
I would appreciated if someone helped me.

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly recommend using the [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) Python distribution.  The full Anaconda distribution includes netcdf4 and the required libraries.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions for Ubuntu are [here](https://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/wiki/UbuntuInstall) which are basically:

**HDF5**

Download the current HDF5 source release.
Unpack, go into the directory and execute:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared --enable-hl
make 
sudo make install
```

To speed things up, compile on more than one processor using

```
make -j n
```

where n is the number of processes to be launched.

**netCDF4**
e
Download the current netCDF4 source release.
Unpack, go into the directory and execute:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include ./configure --enable-netcdf-4 --enable-dap --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local
make 
make install
```

Installing netcdf4-python
When both HDF5 and netCDF4 are in /usr/local, make sure the linker will be able to find those libraries by executing

```
sudo ldconfig
```

then installing netcdf4-python is just a matter of doing

```
python setup.py install
```

Make sure you actually **untar** the files and **cd** to the correct directories.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an alternative wrapper for the netCDF4, like the [netcdf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netcdf) library (it compile the hdf5 and netCDF4 libraries from sourcecode, automatically), using:

```
pip install netcdf
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `pip install netcdf4` ?

Comment: No, thats another library... the one I mention compile the netCDF4 and HDF5 libraries from sources.

Comment: for me `pip install netcdf4` as suggested by @Alf worked, while the solution of @ecolell 's suggestion errored out with `ValueError: did not find HDF5`  headers` in Ubuntu18.04

Answer (score 1):

The netCDF4 python module documentation can be found [here](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/). Check out the "Install" section; it'll have what you're looking for. But, if you satisfy all of the pre-requisites you can simply do the following:

```
python setup.py build && python setup.py install
```

Comment: I could to solve the netcdf4 installation but I do not know where I have to write `python setup.py install`? When I type it I get the following error: `python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` I tried run it in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy$` but  `This is the wrong setup.py file to run`

Answer (score 1):

After much struggle with the installation and getting errors similar to the ones mentioned in this post, I ended up installing it as follows:

1) Installed HDF5

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared --enable-hl
make 
sudo make install
```

2) Installed netcdf4

```
 sudo pip install netcdf4
```

I guess the pip command would have installed the pre-requisite HDF5 as well even if I didn't do step (1). 
Btw, I have *pip version 8.0.2*  and *python 2.7*