# netCDF4 import not being found by Python

Tags: python, netcdf4

I need to use the netCDF4 module in order to do some processing. I have followed the steps on this [guide](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/) and also tried used anaconda2 as recomended on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471751/how-can-i-install-netcdf4-python-to-ubuntu14-04).

netCDF4 seems to be installed, as i can run `nc-config --version` and obtain:

```
netCDF 4.4.0-rc2
```

Although, when i try to import netCDF4 in python with:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
```

It Returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from netCDF4 import Dataset
ImportError: No module named netCDF4
```

I have all dependencies installed. Cython, numpy and h5py. 
It was working last night, before i turned off the PC. When i came back this morning, it just would not work. So if i have netCDF4 installed and can check it's version, how come python is not recognizing it as a module?

Comment: How did you install the package?  With anaconda, `conda install netcdf4` is how I recommend obtaining the package.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i'll try next time something happens... And i believe it will.
I don't know how or why it worked but...
I did a clean uninstall and reinstall of everything i could. h5py, numpy, cython and netcdf. Seemed to work after that. Thanks!

Comment: @N1B4 I'm seeing the same error after using `conda install netcdf4` :(

Answer (score 3):

Convert to project interpreter python 2.7 and then run installation command;

```
pip install netCDF4
```

Answer (score 2):

I used

conda install netcdf4

and it works for python 2.7.